# How to open file and Directory in QT

Tags: qt, qt4, qt-creator

I want to open Directory and file using the same function. Is it possible to do the same in QT.
I used

```
QString directory = QFileDialog::getExistingDirectory(this, tr("Open Directory"),
      "",
     QFileDialog::ShowDirsOnly
     | QFileDialog::DontResolveSymlinks);
```

Here i can open only directory.
How to open both file and directory using single function

Comment: Maybe you should accept one of the answers, or expand your question of none of the answers fit.

Answer (score 2):

Well, I don't think **QFileDialog** can do this job...
Maybe you can use a **QDirModel**. That should do the trick... On clicking your "Browse"-button or something like that, you open a widget with a **QTreeView** using a **QDirModel**, there you can take the selected item and its path as your file/directory. For further information, see the documentation and the Dir View example in Qt Assistant.

**EDIT:**  It is recommended to use [**QFileSystemModel**](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.6/qfilesystemmodel.html) instead of **QDirModel**. Thanks to Patrice for the advice.

Comment: QDirModel must not be used anymore as specified in the documentation: http://doc.trolltech.com/4.6/qdirmodel.html#details

Answer (score 1):

You must use the [`getOpenFileName`](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.6/qfiledialog.html#getOpenFileName) function to get files and [`getExistingDirectory`](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.6/qfiledialog.html#getExistingDirectory) function to get directories. You can not use a unique function from QFileDialog class to do both in the same time.

You have to do it by yourself by:

- subclassing QfileDialog class
  or
- using the [`QFileSystemModel`](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.6/qfilesystemmodel.html) with a [`QTreeView`](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.6/qtreeview.html).